# How do I add an Apple class to a project in Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-mac

I have a really tough question. How would I add a class in Visual Studio for Mac?

More specifically, how do I reference any class?

I'm going through the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/mac/get-started/). It says there is an Audio Player example that uses the AVAudioPlayer class.

It doesn't specifically say how to add that class but going to the Projects > Add Reference menu and typing Audio in the search box shows nothing:

[image]

This is the instruction page I've referenced:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/mac/app-fundamentals/sounds

The page also says it's an example but I don't see any code only an API reference.

**Apple APIs**
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudioplayer#see-also
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudioengine

**UPDATE:**
I think I might have figured it out.

The class looks like it was in AVFoundation package not `AVFAudio`:

[image]

To use it you have to put:

```
using AVFoundation;
```

at the top of your class

Then in your code you can use:

```
var player = new AVAudioPlayer();
```

Or it looks like you can use the full namespace to create an instance:

```
var player = new AVFoundation.AVAudioPlayer();
```

I'm still getting errors so I don't know if that's it or not.

I also added some Nugen libraries like Xamarin.CommunityToolkit but I don't see them referenced in so I don't know if that's necessary.

**Update 2:**
It looks like the instructions for that are here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/nuget-walkthrough?view=vsmac-2019

Here are the errors I'm getting:

> /Applications/Visual
> Studio.app/Contents/Resources/lib/monodevelop/bin/MSBuild/Current/bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(5,5):
> Warning MSB3276: Found conflicts between different versions of the
> same dependent assembly. Please set the "AutoGenerateBindingRedirects"
> property to true in the project file. For more information, see
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=294190. (MSB3276) (project)

> /Users/me/project/packages/Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.1.1.0/build/PreserveXamarinCommunityToolkit.cs(12,12):
> Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'PreserveToolkitAttribute'
> could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
> reference?) (CS0246) (project)

**Side note:**
There doesn't seem to be much activity here on SO, so I attempted to visit the Visual Studio forums and to post you have to join the Microsoft docs network. Here's some of the details when attempting to sign up. They didn't mention this before signing up.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Two things. 1. If you're getting specific errors after the edit you made, you should put them in the question. 2. What does the sign up pages for Microsoft's networks have to do with any of this?

Comment: 1. ok 2. i was getting the impression that there may not be visual studio developers on stack overflow. if that's the case, then before you head to MS Q and A forums be advised that that is the information they will take from you (without permission). they showed me that list of details *after* I signed up for a forum account not at the time i signed up. so until they show you all the information you they will take from you here's a heads up to that and maybe that will persuade people to answer questions here instead.